# A Unicode sentinel value I can use?

Tags: unicode

I am desiging a file format and I want to do it right. Since it is a binary format, the very first byte (or bytes) of the file should *not* form valid textual characters (just like in the PNG file header<sup>1</sup>). This allows tools that do not recognize the format to still see that its not a text file by looking at the first few bytes.

Any codepoint above `0x7F` is invalid US-ASCII, so that's easy. But for Unicode it's a whole different story. Apart from valid Unicode characters there are *private-use characters*, *noncharacters* and *sentinels*, as I found in the [Unicode Private-Use Characters, Noncharacters & Sentinels FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html).

**What would be a sentinel sequence of bytes that I can use at the start of the file that would result in invalid US-ASCII, UTF-8, UTF-16LE and UTF-16BE?**

- Obviously the first byte cannot have a value below `0x80` as that would be a valid US-ASCII (control)character, so `0x00` cannot be used.
- Also, since *private-use characters* are valid Unicode characters, I can't use those codepoints either.
- Since it must work with both little-endian and big-endian UTF-16, a *noncharacter* such as `0xFFFE` is also not possible as its reverse `0xFEFF` is a valid Unicode character.
- The above mentioned FAQ suggests not using any of the *noncharacters* as that would still result in a valid Unicode sequence, so something like `0xFFFF` is also out of the picture.

What would be the future-proof sentinel values that are left for me to use?

---

<sup>1</sup>) The PNG format has as its very first byte the non-ASCII `0x89` value, followed by the string `PNG`. A tool that read the first few bytes of a PNG may determine it is a binary file since it cannot interpret `0x89`. A GIF file, on the other hand, starts directly with the valid and readable ASCII string `GIF` followed by three more valid ASCII characters. For GIF a tool might determine it is a readable text file. This is wrong and the idea of starting the file with a non-textural byte sequence came from [Designing File Formats](http://www.fadden.com/techmisc/file-formats.htm) by Andy McFadden.

Comment: `Since it is a binary format, the first bytes of the file should not form valid textual characters` - You should look at the magic file (/usr/share/magic, or /etc/magic on many unix systems) that shows how this application identifies file types.  A PNG file starts out with `\x89PNG\x0d\0a\x1a\x0a` -- note the "PNG" in there, that's a raw string.  The sequences `\x89` and the like are non-printable bytes.

Comment: @MichaelT Yes, since PNG is a binary format, the first byte does not form a valid textual character. That's what I meant. I fail to see your point?

Comment: Off the top of my head I believe Gifs have "GIF" in their first few bytes too.

Comment: That was an example.  A .gif starts out with `GIF8`.  A SGI movi file starts out with `MOVI`.  One style of zip archive file starts out with `ZZ`, the more popular pkzip format starts out with `PK`.  The constraint that the first byte be an invalid text character does not seem to match what is found in the wild.  I am curious why this is a requirement.

Comment: @MichaelT : I added a response to your concerns at the bottom of my post.

Comment: Do you really care how other programs behave when they see a unknown file? To me, a signature sequence (like PNG files) is much more useful than a sentinel sequence - when the content is sent through a simple stream protocol, the receiver can immediately decide how to handle the following bytes. A Omani-sentinel sequence is next to no-sequence once everyone starts using it to identify their own format.

Comment: @Codism After the sentinel bytes my file format will _too_ have a short ASCII string identifying the file. The sentinel bytes are simply part of the magic signature, just like in PNG files. But PNG files start with the `0x89` sentinel value, which is a valid UTF-8 value, so I'm looking for a different sentinel.

Comment: @Virtlink `0x89` is a continuation byte, it's not valid UTF-8 ever if a file starts with `0x89`.

Comment: I fail to see how using an ASCII character in the header is 'wrong' - especially since many, many programs do this without a problem.  Why does it matter how other tools handle the file?  Ultimately, its a binary file, its going to have non-textual data in there... open it up in a text editor, and its going to look like gibberish regardless of what the header looks like.

Comment: @GrandmasterB What are the _great_ benefits of _not_ doing it? Is it in any way better? Is it so much effort to do it? In a new file format one can pick any magic bytes, so why not pick some that may have at least some benefits, no matter how small?

Comment: @Virtlink, I dont particularly care what bytes you use in your file format.  But you made an assertion that its 'wrong' to use ascii characters... yet I've not seen anything here that supports that claim, and there's plenty of empirical experience that shows it really doesn't matter (ie, the countless file formats that have been using ASCII characters without a problem for decades)

Comment: @GrandmasterB Well, I don't know if it's wrong. I got the idea [from here](http://www.fadden.com/techmisc/file-formats.htm) and I liked it. In general there is a lot that is 'wrong' about many file formats (such as lack of extensibility and future-proofing). That _everyone starts with ASCII characters so I should start with ASCII characters_ does not convince me.

Answer (score 16):

`0xDC 0xDC`

- Obviously invalid UTF-8 and ASCII
- Unpaired trail surrogate in lead position regardless of endianess in UTF-16. It doesn't get more invalid UTF-16 than that.

Comment: But perfectly reasonable ISO-8859-1, and probably reasonable in any other character set that uses an 8-bit encoding.

Comment: +1 OP didn't ask for ISO 8859-1, just US-ASCII and UTF-*.

Comment: @RossPatterson - true, but I suspect that's mostly because the OP hasn't really thought through the problem. Without any statistics to back me up, I'm willing to bet that a random "is this text" algorithm is more likely to give preference to ISO-8859-1 than UTF-16, simply because there's an enormous amount of 8-bit text in the world.

Comment: @parsifal Any binary is valid ISO-8859-1 so it doesn't need to be considered simply because it's impossible to make invalid ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @Esailija - valid, yes, but "text" files don't usually contain control characters (outside of the limited set of whitespace characters).

Comment: @parsifal true and if that was the requirement you could just use `0x00` or whatever, but op didn't want that.

Answer (score 5):

- In UTF-8, the bytes C0, C1, and F5 - FF are illegal. The first byte must either be ASCII or a byte in the range C2-F4, any other starting byte is not valid UTF-8.
- In UTF-16, the file *normally* starts with the Byte Order Mark (U+FEFF), otherwise applications have to guess at the byte order. Codepoints in the range D800-DBFF are lead bytes for a surrogate pair, and DC00-DFFF are the trailing bytes for a surrogate pair.

Thus, I'd use the byte combo `F5DC`. These two values are:

- Not ASCII
- Not valid UTF-8
- Either interpreted as a UTF-16 trailing byte in a surrogate pair (not legal), or the codepoint U+F5DC, which is a private use character, but *only* by applications that stubbornly try to interpret this as UTF-16 even without a BOM.

If you need more options, `F5DD` through to `F5DF` all have the same 3 properties, as do `F6DC` - `F6DF`, `F7DC` - `F7DF` and `F8DC` - `F8DF`, for a total of 16 different byte combos to pick from.

Comment: So, by [Esailija's suggestion](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/190417/48260) to use U+DCDC, `0xDC` would be valid UTF-8?

Comment: @Virtlink `0xDC` is a UTF-8 lead byte for a 2-byte sequence. It must be followed by a `10xxxxxx` continuation byte for it to be valid. `0xDC` is not a valid continuation byte, so `0xDC 0xDC` is not valid UTF-8.

Comment: @Virtlink: No, because the second byte is not valid, it would have to be in the range `80` - `BF`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to use a non-printable character to indicate "not text," then you'll find it hard to beat 0x89:

- It's outside the US-ASCII range
- In ISO-8859-1 it's a non-printable character ("CHARACTER TABULATION WITH JUSTIFICATION "). Likewise with Shift-JIS, which I believe is still in common use. Other 8-bit encodings may, however treat this as a valid character.
- In UTF-8 it's an invalid first-byte for a multi-byte sequence (top bits are 10, which are reserved for characters 2..N of a multi-byte sequence)

Generally, when you form magic numbers, "non-text" is a minor point. I'll have to look up the reference, but one of the standard graphics formats (TIFF, I think) has something like six different pieces of useful information from its magic number.